# Any downsides to having both 401k AND Roth 401k

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, retirement, roth-401k

So currently I have a 401k, I went ahead and added a Roth 401k while I'm eligible, beyond the fact I'll have to pay tax on the contributions now without the tax on withdrawal later in life you'd see on a regular 401k, are there any potential unconsidered negatives of keeping both?

Also, in retrospect are there any additional positives I may not have considered that make it more evidently positive to have both as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the mix is chosen correctly, you have the opportunity to (for example) use Roth to save 15% taxed money, then shift to pretax for 25% income. On retiring, you then take withdrawals from the pretax account only up to a taxable 15%, then Roth for the rest of your spending.

This is an oversimplification. In reality, you need to analyze where you are today, where you expect to be on retiring, and pay some attention every year in between.

Comment: Ah see, that's the sort of thing I could use direction to some documentation regarding how to measure those metrics and responsibly conduct them accordingly.

Comment: http://www.joetaxpayer.com/the-15-solution/ is an article I wrote to address this issue.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer you've got what looks like a spam comment at the bottom of that article.

Comment: The primary reason to like the 401(k) in my mind would be if there is an employer match. That is free money that will compound over time. Unclear whether it would apply to your situatuion, but you would not want to pass up the match.

Comment: @JAGAnalyst - agreed, but the question was really traditional vs Roth flavors. When companies offer match either account gets a match to the traditional side.

Comment: I thought that I had some basic understanding of  traditional vs Roth issues but the above answer baffles me. What happens at age 70.5 when mandatory distributions from the pretax account kick in?

Comment: @DilipSarwate - specifically which aspect? 401(k) has an RMD for both flavors. An odd thing not discussed enough. Need to convert to IRA to avoid RMDs if you wish.

Comment: Ya I get dollar for dollar up to 3%

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no downsides to having both. In fact, it is very good to have both traditional and Roth plans so that you could plan your tax and tax free withdrawals and time them in the most beneficial way for you.